# How to make use of the private Qt C++ API?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to use the `QBalloonTip` class to generate a stilized tooltip for a button with QT 5.8.0.

What I've tried until now is modify the header file `qsystemtrayicon_p.h` the method `QBalloonTip::showBalloon(...)` by giving default arguments. However even when I included the header `qsystemtrayicon_p.h` in my code, I'm having problems when linking the compiled sourced code. Next error appears:

`LNK2019: unresolved external symbol: "public static void QBalloonTip::showBalloon(...)"`

Hope anyone has faced this before. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can inherit from QBalloonTip and override the relevant methods.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do, but if you change the type or number of parameters that will declare a new function that doesn't match the one in the library.

Comment: Check this out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9JD8gKGZ00

Answer (score 3):

To use Qt's private API, you have to explicitly include it in your `.pro` file:

```
QT += widgets-private
```

However, it is not recommended to do that, as the private APIs are not documented and tie you to the specific Qt version you built with. If your Code is GPL compliant, you should propably rather copy the sources of the balloontip class into your application.

Furthermore, this will not solve your problem, as you can't simply modify a header to an already compiled library. This is simply not possible. Either try to inherit from that class, or copy the sources into your project and modify them there.

Comment: Hello Felix, I already tried that but the error still appears. I also added QBalloonTip class as a friend in my class in order to use its public methods. Actually at the end I did not modify anything from the header file. This QBalloonTip is being used by the class QSystemTrayIcon. However I wanted to use this QBalloonTip class direclty. I think I will give up with this alternative, I've spent almost 3 weeks on this. I'll go with Scopchanov solution. Thank you

Comment: @JoelRuiz, Just for information - adding a class as a friend won't give you an access to its members. It works the oposite way - the friend class will have access to the members of the class in which it is declared as a friend.